# C/C++ reading binary file with multiple strings and chars

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc, fread

My objective is to read from a binary file over a hundred of 'sequences' (non-technical term), each comprising of a char1 (length of the string to follow), string1, char2, string2. The key things here seem to be dynamic memory allocation, pointers and looping. This is how I did it:

```
char *ColumnNameLength = (char *) malloc(Repetitions * sizeof(char));
char *DataTypeLength = (char *) malloc(Repetitions * sizeof(char)); 
char **ColumnName = (char **) malloc(Repetitions * sizeof(char));
char **DataType = (char **) malloc(Repetitions * sizeof(char));

for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= Repetitions ; ColumnNameLength[ctr] = DataTypeLength[ctr] = NULL, ctr++)
    ;
for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= Repetitions ; *(ColumnName+ctr) = DataType[ctr] = NULL, ctr++)
    ;

for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= FieldCount; ctr++)
{
    fread((ColumnNameLength + ctr), sizeof(char), 1, pInfile);

    *(ColumnName + ctr) = (char *) malloc(ColumnNameLength[ctr] * sizeof(char));
    fread(ColumnName[ctr], sizeof(char), ColumnNameLength[ctr], pInfile);
    //I should add '\0' at the end of each read string, but no idea how

    fread((DataTypeLength + ctr), sizeof(char), 1, pInfile);

    *(DataType + ctr) = (char *) malloc(DataTypeLength[ctr] * sizeof(char));
    fread(&DataType[ctr], sizeof(char), DataTypeLength[ctr], pInfile);
    //I should add '\0' at the end of each read string, but no idea how

}
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I do not even know were to start debugging. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Advice: Choose either `C++` or `C`.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure to allocate the string arrays using `sizeof(char*)` not `sizeof(char)`.
- Perhaps use `unsigned char` for lengths, to avoid sign confusion.
- Allocate one more character for trailing `'\0'`.
- Add trailing null byte using `ColumnName[ctr][ColumnNameLength[ctr]] = '\0'`.
- Add some error checking in case `malloc` returnins `NULL`.
- Add error checking in case `fread` returns something other than the length.
- In future questions, be more specific about what actually fails.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I feel I am getting somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The first bug i see in your code is using <= instead of < , you have `ColumnNameLength` chars to go over, thus from index 0 to index `ColumnNameLength -1`.

It's weird to me that you are using a pointer to pointer instead of using a char array for saving the string.

Comment: pointer of pointers is a common way in C to hold a dynamic array of strings.

Comment: Maybe i didn't pay attention to what he meant, but if he meant array of strings then it should be pointer of pointers.

Comment: `char **ColumnName` _is_ a pointer of pointers.  As is `char **DataType`

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ColumnNameLength = (char *) malloc(Repetitions * sizeof(char));
char *DataTypeLength = (char *) malloc(Repetitions * sizeof(char)); 
char **ColumnName = (char **) malloc(Repetitions * sizeof(char*));
char **DataType = (char **) malloc(Repetitions * sizeof(char*));

for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= Repetitions ; ColumnNameLength[ctr] = DataTypeLength[ctr] = NULL, ctr++)
    ;
for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= Repetitions ; ColumnName[ctr] = DataType[ctr] = NULL, ctr++)
    ;

for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= FieldCount; ctr++)
{
    fread((ColumnNameLength + ctr), sizeof(char), 1, pInfile);

    ColumnName[ctr] = (char *) malloc((ColumnNameLength[ctr]+1) * sizeof(char));
    fread(ColumnName[ctr], sizeof(char), ColumnNameLength[ctr], pInfile);
    //I should add '\0' at the end of each read string, but no idea how
    ColumnName[ctr][ColumnNameLength[ctr]] = '\0';

    fread((DataTypeLength + ctr), sizeof(char), 1, pInfile);

    DataType[ctr] = (char *) malloc((DataTypeLength[ctr]+1) * sizeof(char));
    fread(DataType[ctr], sizeof(char), DataTypeLength[ctr], pInfile);
    //I should add '\0' at the end of each read string, but no idea how
    DataType[ctr][DataTypeLength[ctr]] = '\0';

}
```

Comment: Cheers for saving me the trouble of applying the above comments ;) It compiles nicely